# how to clear file before putting data there?

Tags: java, io

I need to save some data into text file. I'm using class `Files` with its method `write()`.
If such file doesn't exist - everything alright. The problem is if such file already exists it appends new data to the end of the file. And I need to clear it first. The code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DepoList test0 = new DepoList();
    test0.init();
    ArrayList<Depo> list0 = test0.getList();
    Collections.sort(list0);

    for (Depo depo : list0) {
        String str = String.format("sum = %1$8.2f   interest =  %2$7.2f\n", depo.getSum(), depo.getIncome());
        System.out.format(str);
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get("depo.txt"), str.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
```

I think I need to add some another `StandardOpenOperation`. How to clear the file before putting data there?

Comment: True. Otherwise it creates file with only one last string.

Comment: [StandardOpenOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)

Comment: Have you even looked at the other `StandardOpenOption`s? There seems to be obvious choices...

Answer (score 2):

Remove `StandardOpenOption.CREATE,Standardoption.APPEND` this just appends your new data to the existing one

Use `Files.write((Paths.get("depo.txt"), str.getBytes());`

Comment: in this case it only adds one value `sum = 43000,00   interest =  8526,02`
and i need:
`sum =  5500,00   interest =    69,16
sum =  2500,00   interest =    75,21
sum = 12000,00   interest =   478,68
sum = 10000,00   interest =  1041,37
sum = 43000,00   interest =  8526,02
`

Comment: Do you want to clear the file before writing or do you not ? If you want to append it, youll get `sum = 5500,00 interest = 69,16 sum = 2500,00 interest = 75,21 sum = 12000,00 interest = 478,68 sum = 10000,00 interest = 1041,37 sum = 43000,00 interest = 8526,02 ` if you dont, youll only get the last string

Comment: yes i want to clear file before writing data there. How to do that?